# Use your voice to search for and perform an action in Word

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word, microsoft-office-2021

According to Microsoft, it's possible to search command by using voice in Microsoft Office (I've Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2021):

[image]

In my case I cannot see the microphone button. Do you know how to use it?

[image]

---

EDIT: why in my options there aren't Intelligent Services?

[image]

[image]

---

EDIT 2: I have both italian and english language packages installed

[image]

Comment: Hello @harrymc my Windows version is 10 Home 21H2. The Office version is professional plus 2021 2210

Comment: I'm using Word 365 and my Home panel has a Dictate button. If yours doesn't have it, check if in *Control Panel > Speech Recognition* you can use "Start Speech Recognition".

Comment: Thank you very much @harrymc it's an operating system problem; it says that the speech recognition is not available in the current language

Comment: What is your language?

Comment: @harrymc both Windows and Office are in italian; I tried to set office in english, but the result is the same so maybe I need to set also Windows in english

Comment: Italian [is supported](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/use-voice-typing-to-talk-instead-of-type-on-your-pc-fec94565-c4bd-329d-e59a-af033fa5689f#bkmk_supportedlanguages).

Comment: @harrymc it's quite strange that I got that message, maybe there is another problem

Answer (score 0):

To install Speech Recognition for your language :

- Enter *Settings > Time & language > Language*
- Click your language
- Click *Options*
- Under Speech, click *Download*
- Sign out and back again for the new speech pack to be added
  to speech options
- Back in *Settings > Time & language > Language*, ensure your language
  is at to the top of the list and is the default
- Enter *Settings > Time & language > Speech*
- Under "Speech language", ensure that your language is chosen
- Sign out and back again.

If everything has passed well, you should now have in Word's
Home panel a Dictate button.

Otherwise, check if in *Control Panel > Speech Recognition*
you can use "Start Speech Recognition".

Comment: the italian package was already there, I installed also the english one, but the message is the same (see edit 2 please)

Comment: My advice was to have Italian as the first language - click it and then the up-arrow.

Comment: the arrow doesn't work, it seems that I cannot change the order

Comment: Try moving English down instead?

Comment: same result, maybe my Windows 10 is very old

Comment: I recommend updating it to the latest version of Windows 10 (not Windows 11).

Comment: when I go in windows update, it says that the latest updates are installed (I cannot install Windows 11 because my PC doesn't have the requirements)

Comment: Try to test Windows integrity by running [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: I'm a bit scared, should I do a backup before?

Comment: Backup is always a good idea, but these operations should be harmless.

Comment: @harrymc Apparently the OP hasn't the required subscription.

Answer (score 0):

From the question:

> EDIT: why in my options there aren't Intelligent Services?

There are a lot on the web, among everything also about **how to search inside Words documents using voice**. I prefer to look first, whenever is about Microsoft products, at the Microsoft support articles and blogs, focusing on the last version. No surprises here, there are requirements, it's required to have a **Microsoft 365 subscription** and to opt in.

Note: The image included in the question shows this requirement but you do not mention to have the required subscription.

AIn order to be able to use voice to search in Word documents using the feature by Microsoft your next step is to buy a Microsoft 365 subscription.

References:

- Microsoft 365 Support: [Search with your voice in Word](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/search-with-your-voice-in-word-9b24ab5e-6747-4b5a-a08d-35564e4e6a4a)
- Windows Insider blog: [Search with your voice in Word for Windows](https://insider.office.com/en-us/blog/search-with-your-voice-in-word-for-windows)