# Searching words in a document by using the voice

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word, search, documents, google-docs

I'm wondering if there is a way to search a word in a document by using the voice.

So far I tried to do it in Microsoft Word, Google Docs, but without any success; it seems that this option is not available.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use your voice to search for and perform an action in Word](https://superuser.com/questions/1754622/use-your-voice-to-search-for-and-perform-an-action-in-word)

Comment: Hello @CharlesKenyon the other answer is not related to this one because Microsoft Word allows to search commands, not words by using voice. Here I'm asking how to search words in the text by voice

Comment: There is not a built in way to do this in Word. You can use voice typing using either the built in Windows functions or a 3rd party tool in conjunction with the product's search feature.

Comment: Hello @music2myear have you tried any method?

Comment: No, but based on my own experience with the distinct parts I've suggested, I'd imagine it is completely achievable. You should be able to look into the built in Windows voice controls easily.

Comment: Please provide more details, like name and version of the operative system. Also provide details of what you have tried as well a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask]. I suggest you to reduce the focus of your question to a single app. You might post another question to ask about the other app.

Comment: Hello @Rubén thank you for your suggestions. I'm using windows 10, version 21H2.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The question still looks to require more focus, regarding the Microsoft Word part, I think that this question is actually a duplicate of the first link. I will post an answer there.